# Flagging the top 20% of records in a BigQuery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of data that looks like this:

| id | colour | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | 13.5 |
| 2 | blue | 12.7 |
| 3 | blue | 19.5 |

I would like to create a new column that shows whether the `id` has a `value` in the top 20% of all values with that same `colour`. Desired output:

| id | colour | value | top_20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | 13.5 | TRUE |
| 2 | blue | 12.7 | FALSE |
| 3 | blue | 19.5 | TRUE |

In this example, row 1 has a value of 13.5 and this is in the top 20% of all values for records with the colour red,row two has a value of 12.7 which is not in the top 20% of values for "blue", but row 3 is.

What is the best way to make this calculation in Google BigQuery?

Comment: What if there are duplicates for `value` for a color?  So, if there are five rows for `'red'` with the value `13.5`, would all five rows be marked `top_20` or just 1?

Comment: All five would be flagged for this example.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the function [PERCENTILE_CONT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#percentile_cont) and compare the result to the value itself. In case the percentile is less than the value, apply a true/false statement:

```
select
  *,

  -- Show the percentile
  percentile_cont(value, 0.8) over (partition by colour) as percentile_80,

  -- When 80th percentile value is less than or equal to the value itself, then that's top20
  IF(percentile_cont(value, 0.8) over (partition by colour) <= value, true, false) as top_20

from
  table_data
```

Comment: The `if` is redundant and I think the answer would be clearer using `0.2` and a descending sort, but the approach is correct.